# In Python, how could I convert a whitespace-delimited log output to a Markdown-formatted table?

Tags: python, replace, markdown, whitespace, tabular

In Python, how could I convert a whitespace-delimited log output to a Markdown-formatted table?

I have an output log that contains printouts of the following form:

```
 - e_jets cutflow:
                                  cut         events
      1                       INITIAL          13598
      2                           GRL           7250
      3               EL_N 25000 >= 1            326
      4               EL_N 25000 == 1            313
      5               MU_N 25000 == 0            313
      6             JETCLEAN LooseBad            313
      7              JET_N 25000 >= 1            113
      8              JET_N 25000 >= 2             26
      9              JET_N 25000 >= 3              8
     10              JET_N 25000 >= 4              2
     11      MVA_BTAG MV2c20 -0.4434               2
     12                     VARIABLES              2
     13                          SAVE              2

 - mu_jets cutflow:
                                  cut         events
      1                       INITIAL          13598
      2                           GRL           7250
      3               MU_N 25000 >= 1            326
      4               MU_N 25000 == 1            313
      5               EL_N 25000 == 0            313
      6             JETCLEAN LooseBad            313
      7              JET_N 25000 >= 1            127
      8              JET_N 25000 >= 2             47
      9              JET_N 25000 >= 3             15
     10              JET_N 25000 >= 4              4
     11      MVA_BTAG MV2c20 -0.4434               4
     12                     VARIABLES              4
     13                          SAVE              4
```

I want to convert this to a form like the following (Markdown tables):

```
|**e_jets cutflow**|**cut**|**events**|
|---|---|---|
|1|INITIAL|13598|
|2|GRL|7250|
|3|EL_N 25000 >= 1|326|
|4|EL_N 25000 == 1|313|
|5|MU_N 25000 == 0|313|
|6|JETCLEAN LooseBad|313|
|7|JET_N 25000 >= 1|113|
|8|JET_N 25000 >= 2|26|
|9|JET_N 25000 >= 3|8|
|10|JET_N 25000 >= 4|2|
|11|MVA_BTAG MV2c20 -0.4434|2|
|12|VARIABLES|2|
|13|SAVE|2|

|**mu_jets cutflow**|**cut**|**events**|
|---|---|---|
|1|INITIAL|13598|
|2|GRL|7250|
|3|MU_N 25000 >= 1|326|
|4|MU_N 25000 == 1|313|
|5|EL_N 25000 == 0|313|
|6|JETCLEAN LooseBad|313|
|7|JET_N 25000 >= 1|127|
|8|JET_N 25000 >= 2|47|
|9|JET_N 25000 >= 3|15|
|10|JET_N 25000 >= 4|4|
|11|MVA_BTAG MV2c20 -0.4434|4|
|12|VARIABLES|4|
|13|SAVE|4|
```

One way to do this could be to replace two or more consecutive spaces with a vertical bar character. How could I do this in an efficient way? Given that the table is always to have three columns, is there a better, more robust way to do this?

Comment: What *specific coding problem* did you encounter when trying to implement your solution? And how did you determine that it wasn't efficient/robust?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how to do something that would be simple and space-efficient like string ```split``` or string ```replace``` because the number of spaces changes depending on the entries. My current idea would involve a lot of ```if``` statements. The fact that there can be spaces in the entries rather than their delimiters confuses matters.

Comment: Have you considered using a regular expression (e.g. https://regex101.com/r/tJ3vB4/1)?

Comment: Stop worrying about optimisation (which is completely irrelevant 90% of the time), and start writing some code that just does what you want it to do.

Comment: Have you considered Python's [cvs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module? You can specific a deliminator other than a comma. That should give you a Python data structure which you could then do whatever you wanted with.

Comment: Is that space deliminated or tab deliminated? I notice that the data also contains spaces within individual fields which are not quoted. If it is space deliminated, is the assumption that two or more spaces delimit? Without that info, it is difficult to provide an accurate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question, comments, and sample data exactly as it is posted (all spaces, no tabs), my assumption is that the real question is how to handle the fact that each line in the data contains a different number of spaces between each field.

Assuming that spaces can appear within a field, but only one at a time, and that two or more spaces delimit a field, the following regex would easily find the breaks between each field (two or more spaces):

```
[ ]{2,}
```

Then use a substitution to replace all the deliminators:

```
output = re.sub(r'[ ]{2,}', input, '|')
```

Of course, that doesn't handle the line endings or the heading. But for the heading, you will probably want to split on lines anyway, so you can handle the end of the line also:

```
SPACES_RE = re.compile(r'[ ]{2,}')

new_lines  []
for line in input.split('\n'):
    new_lines.append(SPACES_RE.sub(line, '|'))
output = '|\n'.join(new_lines)
```

Now, just add an if statement or two within the loop to detect the heading and format it appropriately and you have a working solution. As that wasn't specifically asked about, I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and for your helpful guidance on using regex for this problem. I am using some of your ideas together with filtering and splitting: ```entries = filter(None, line.split("  "))```.